# If it is possible Android has a JVM then byte code should run on Android?

Tags: java, android

I read many links on Stack Overflow but I'm confused. Java is platform independent; then why can't byte code run on the Android OS?

If it is possible Android os (on mobile) has a **JVM** then byte code should run on Android.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: **NO, you can't**

long answer: 
Android applications are usually written in Java language and are executed in the Dalvik Virtual Machine (DVM), which is different from the classical Java Virtual Machine (JVM). The DVM is developed by Google and optimized for the characteristics of mobile operating systems (especially for the Android platform).

The bytecode running in Dalvik is transferred from traditional JVM bytecode to the dex-format by translating Java .class files with the conversion tool dx.

Contrary to the DVM, JVM is using pure Java class files.

[image]

Comment: In my understanding Dalvik has been discontinued, and is replaced by ART. http://www.extremetech.com/computing/184889-dalvik-is-dead-next-version-of-android-uses-new-art-runtime-to-boost-speed-battery-life

Comment: #dev dabhi .Review this well answer .